# How to make custom error pages appear on production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, iis-7.5, custom-errors

i am troubled by custom error in mvc 4 in production server. The custom error pages works on my development machine. but not when published in IIS8.. here is my web.config

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/Message/DefaultError" >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Message/Error404" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Message/Error500"/>
</customErrors>
</system.web>
 <system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough" defaultPath="/Message/DefaultError">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Message/Error404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Message/Error500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

and i wonder why does this settings don't work when they are published.. Any ideas out there fellas

Answer (score 1):

Try these modifications in `web.config` file :

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom"  defaultResponseMode="Redirect">
 <remove statusCode="404"/>
 <error responseMode="ExecuteURL" statusCode="404" path="/Message/Error404" />
 </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: so what's the result @EduCielo ?

Comment: iT'S working now.. this should be added as well as the custom errors section in system.web. i also change existingResponse="PassThrough"  and defaultResponseMode="Redirect" to defaultResponseMode="execute"